# Is there a way to have a local install of IBM DOORS for the purpose of practising DXL use?

Tags: ibm-doors

I am interested in furthering my DORS DXL skillset, however would like to progress this knowledge in my own time at home rather than staying at work where it is installed!

I was wondering is there a method to download and install IBM DOORS on my home PC for the purpose of practising beginner DXL coding (e.g. scripting to copy data from A to B).

Note: appreciate the usual setup for DOORS is a client / server relationship rather than local version so expect the answer is no!

Answer (score 1):

DOORS client cannot run without a server, but it is not a problem to set up a DOORS server and client on your own PC (I have had up to three DOORS servers at the same time on my machine, depending on my current tasks), but you will need a license for the client to run. If you want to learn DXL for being able to work for your employer, you can ask him to contact your IBM sales representative for a trial / testing license that is valid for some months.